# Problem to test a HttpRequest with a HttpResponse with WireMock

Tags: java, wiremock

With below code, it arises an error: `<h1>Bad Message 400</h1><pre>reason: Bad Request</pre>`

```
    @Test
    public void basicWireMockTest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // Setup the WireMock mapping stub for the test
        CriticNotification r = CriticNotificationServiceUnitTest.getCriticNotification();
        String filterCreated = (filterBuilder.createFilter(r));
        String url = filterBuilder.getUri(false, r.getVirtualPair());
        String completeUrl = filterBuilder.generateCompleteFilter(url, filterCreated).replaceFirst(url, "");
        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(FilterBuilderImpl.URI_PATH)
                .withHeader("Connection", containing("close"))
                .withHeader("Content-Type", containing("application/json"))
                .withHeader("Authorization", containing(filterBuilder.getAuthorization()))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withHeader("Connection", "close")
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBodyFile("**responseGet.json**")));
        // Setup HTTP GET request (with HTTP Client embedded in Java 17+)
        final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
        final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Connection", "close")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", filterBuilder.getAuthorization())
                .uri(URI.create(wireMockServer.url(completeUrl)))
                .GET()
                .build();
        // Send the request and receive the response
        final HttpResponse<String> response =
                client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(response.request().uri().toURL().toString() + "[" + **response.headers().toString()** + "]");
        System.out.println(response.body());
```

I am using:
`import java.net.http.HttpClient; import java.net.http.HttpRequest; import java.net.http.HttpResponse;`

## Bad Message 400

```
reason: Bad Request
```

This is in response.body(), and I expect what is defined in configuration file (specifically body.json):

There are two files in __files directory: **responseGet.json** and body.json

responseGet.json content:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/objectserver/restapi/alerts/status",
    "headers": {
      "Connection": {
        "contains": "close"
      },
      "Content-Type": {
        "contains": "application/json"
      },
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {"Connection": "close","Content-Type": "application/json"},
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "body.json"
  }
}
```

body.json content:

```
{
  "rowset": {
    "osname": "CNSAADP",
    "tblname": "status",
    "rows": [
      {
        "Serial": 2114264833,
        "ServerName": "CNSPCC2"
      }
    ],
    "affectedRows": 1,
    "coldesc": [
      {
        "name": "Serial",
        "type": "integer",
        "size": 4
      },
      {
        "name": "ServerName",
        "type": "string",
        "size": 64
      }
    ],
    "dbname": "alerts"
  }
}
```

I think problem is related to response headers because this is what I receive like them:

`java.net.http.HttpHeaders@161e87ad { {connection=[close], content-length=[54], content-type=[text/html;charset=iso-8859-1]} }`

This output is given from: **response.headers().toString()**

Any ideas, why I do not receive like body.json file content?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

Instead of using responseGet.json file, I use body.json. And also when it is created the request I added the version, like this:

```
final HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .header("Connection", "close")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("Authorization", filterBuilder.getAuthorization())
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .uri(URI.create(wireMockServer.url(completeUrl)))
            .GET()
            .build();
```